# select * count(id) num from table_name

Tags: mysql

we can do it,

> eg:select * ,count(id) from table_name

but select count(id),* from table_name is wrong.why the * must put the first ?

> eg:select count(id),* from table_name

Comment: Neither of these is correct.  In general, `count()` without `group by` is wrong -- especially when you are choosing other columns.

Comment: If you can share some sample table data and your expected output, maybe someone can give you a correct query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure this is meant to be a full query.

Comment: I think `select count(id), table_name.*` would be valid.

Comment: @shmosel Jan,yes ,you are right. the start need to put the first if you want yto use it directly.